# spring jdbcauthentication stackoverflowerror

Tags: spring, spring-security

trying to configure jdbc authentication.  i'm able to use an in memory db, but once I change to jdbc, it's failing.

here's my web security:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;


@Autowired
public void registerGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth
    .jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .withUser("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER").and().withUser("testuser").password("test").roles("ADMIN","USER");

  }
```

}

My login page comes up fine.  enter the credentials and I get stuck in an endless loop error:

```
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-5" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.isDisabled(Hierarchy.java:356)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.isDebugEnabled(Category.java:734)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.isDebugEnabled(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:199)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.isDebugEnabled(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:423)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:423)
```

This works fine if I use an embedded db (H2), but fails with Oracle.

any help is appreciated.

thx

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same cyclic authentication error. Got it working by removing:

```
.withUser("user")
        .password("password")
        .roles("USER").and().withUser("testuser").password("test").roles("ADMIN","USER");
```

And adding to your configure http:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

     http (... loginPage etc)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
    ;
}
```

Class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityJDBCConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource);
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/enter")
            .failureUrl("/enter?error")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("AUTH");
}

}
```

Be sure to have your db tables setup with a valid user/role inserted.